# Why does $\ln(2+\tan\theta) - \frac{1}{2}\ln(1+\tan^2\theta) =\ln (\frac{2 + \tan\theta}{\sec\theta})$?

Tags: trigonometry, logarithms

How is it that

$$\ln(2+\tan\theta) - \frac{1}{2}\ln\left(1+\tan^2\theta\right) = \ln \left(\frac{2 + \tan\theta}{\sec\theta}\right)$$

Comment: Please indicate your approach.

Comment: A necessary condition to have your homework done by others is to copy it correctly. A sufficient condition is to include honest attempts of solving it yourself. Unfortunately, not a necessary condition neither a sufficient one has been displayed here, so I move to down vote.

Comment: Sorry I have modified the question. It should be correct now.

Comment: @uniquesolution interesting comment :)

Comment: Thanks I got it.  My main problem was getting rid of the $-\frac{1}{2}$.  After doing that I was easily able to apply the log rule and solve this question. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\ln(2+\tan\theta) - \frac{1}{2}\ln\left(1+\tan^2\theta\right) = \ln \left(\frac{2 + \tan\theta}{\sec\theta}\right)$$

$$\ln(2+\tan\theta) - \ln\left(\sec \theta\right ) = \ln \left(\frac{2 + \tan\theta}{\sec\theta}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$1+\tan^2\theta=\sec^2\theta$$ and 
$$\ln x- \frac{1}{2}\ln y=\ln x-\ln y^{\frac{1}{2}}=\ln\frac{x}{y^\frac{1}{2}}.$$
I think you can finish from here.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{align}\ln(1+\tan\theta) - \frac{1}{2}\ln(1+\tan^2\theta) = & \ln \left(\frac{2 + \tan\theta}{\sec\theta}\right)\\= 
&\ln\left(\frac{(1+\tan\theta)}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2\theta}}\right)\\=
&\ln\left(\frac{(1+\tan\theta)}{\sqrt{\sec^2\theta}}\right)\\=
&\ln \left(\frac{1 + \tan\theta}{\lvert\sec\theta\rvert}\right)
\end{align}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
Forget $\sec \theta$ (it's just $\dfrac1{\cos\theta}$) and remember $1+\tan^2\theta=\dfrac1{\cos^2\theta}.$